# How to load data.frame made by phyloseq::psmelt from disc?

Tags: r, dataframe, save, load, phyloseq

Melting `phyloseq` data for easier plotting takes long time with 
`df = psmelt(pseq)` so I want to save the created `df` data.frame to disc for faster recovering in case of any crash. Using `save(df,file="filename.Rda")` creates file which is supposed to be reloaded by `df = load("finename.Rda")`.

`str(df)` returns `'data.frame':  1294700 obs. of  23 variables:...`

after `df = load("filename.Rda")`  the `df` appears in "values" not "data" and is quite small.

How to properly load the saved data preserving its structure, etc.???

Best regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it should be simply `load(filename.Rda)` , no `df =`, and it goes where it should be and as it supposed to be.